# Enabling/Disabling RegularExpressionValidator in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem with RegularExpressionValidator connected with TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbPRCOD" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Green" BackColor="White" BorderStyle="None" Width="50%"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="revPRCOD" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="True"
                                 ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:GlobalTranslations, max20char %>" Display="Dynamic"
                                 ControlToValidate="tbPRCOD" BackColor="Transparent" Font-Bold="True"
                                 Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}$">
```

On page I have Drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbIDFAM" runat="server" Width="98%" SkinID="mandatoryCombo" Font-Size="X-Small" AutoPostBack="true" > </asp:DropDownList></td>
```

At start validator is enabled (if string in text box will be over 20 characeters then validator shows validate error). If I change selected item in DropDownList to item with value 5 then I want to turn off validation because for this index in DropDownList, I want to write in TextBox (tbPRCOD) more than 20 characters:

```
        Protected Sub cmbIDFAM_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbIDFAM.SelectedIndexChanged
        If getValueFromCombo(cmbIDFAM) = 5 Then
            tbPRCOD.MaxLength = 100
            revPRCOD.Enabled = False

        Else
            tbPRCOD.MaxLength = 20
            revPRCOD.Enabled = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

Everything works fine until I change cmbIDFAM DropDownList to 5th item. I put in TextBox more than 20 characters, and now RegularExpressionValidator is disabled so it don't show error in validate. When I change item in ddl then in TextBox is more than 20 characters and validator is enabled, but error doesn't show in page. Why? How to force validation? I also use function to force Validation, after change item in ddl:

```
revPRCOD.Validate()
```

This won't help in this situation. Thanks for Help.
Mat.

Comment: Is this the only place in the code behind where you modify value of `revPRCOD.Enabled`?